# SQL: Summing across CASE statements returning wrong result

Tags: sql, wordpress, woocommerce

It's been ages since I've written complex SQL statements. I'm working in WordPress/WooCommerce and trying to sum orders against each customer.

When I started testing with this SQL statement, to just get a list of orders with customer info included, it works:

```
SELECT wp_users.ID as userID,
       wp_posts.post_date,
       wp_posts.post_type,
       wp_users.user_email,
       MAX(CASE WHEN wp_usermeta.meta_key = 'billing_first_name' THEN wp_usermeta.meta_value END) as firstName,
       MAX(CASE WHEN wp_usermeta.meta_key = 'billing_last_name' THEN wp_usermeta.meta_value END) as lastName,
       MAX(CASE WHEN wp_woocommerce_order_itemmeta.meta_key = '_line_total' THEN wp_woocommerce_order_itemmeta.meta_value END) as orderTotal

FROM wp_posts
  INNER JOIN wp_postmeta
     ON wp_postmeta.post_id = wp_posts.ID
  INNER JOIN wp_users
     ON wp_postmeta.meta_key = '_customer_user'
     AND wp_users.ID = wp_postmeta.meta_value
  INNER JOIN wp_usermeta
     ON wp_usermeta.user_id = wp_users.ID
  INNER JOIN wp_woocommerce_order_items
     ON wp_woocommerce_order_items.order_id = wp_posts.ID
  INNER JOIN wp_woocommerce_order_itemmeta
     ON wp_woocommerce_order_itemmeta.order_item_id = wp_woocommerce_order_items.order_item_id
WHERE wp_posts.post_type IN ('shop_order','shop_subscription') 
GROUP BY wp_posts.ID
```

Result is shown in the first image here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/baDwi.jpg

And if I sum those results in excel (there is only 1 test user so far), it shows $4281 as the total for that user.

If I then try and SUM in the SQL statement per user, like here (only two lines are changed, last MAX changed to SUM, and GROUP BY changed to wp_users.ID):

```
SELECT wp_users.ID as userID,
       wp_posts.post_date,
       wp_posts.post_type,
       wp_users.user_email,
       MAX(CASE WHEN wp_usermeta.meta_key = 'billing_first_name' THEN wp_usermeta.meta_value END) as firstName,
       MAX(CASE WHEN wp_usermeta.meta_key = 'billing_last_name' THEN wp_usermeta.meta_value END) as lastName,
       SUM(CASE WHEN wp_woocommerce_order_itemmeta.meta_key = '_line_total' THEN wp_woocommerce_order_itemmeta.meta_value END) as userTotal

FROM wp_posts
  INNER JOIN wp_postmeta
     ON wp_postmeta.post_id = wp_posts.ID
  INNER JOIN wp_users
     ON wp_postmeta.meta_key = '_customer_user'
     AND wp_users.ID = wp_postmeta.meta_value
  INNER JOIN wp_usermeta
     ON wp_usermeta.user_id = wp_users.ID
  INNER JOIN wp_woocommerce_order_items
     ON wp_woocommerce_order_items.order_id = wp_posts.ID
  INNER JOIN wp_woocommerce_order_itemmeta
     ON wp_woocommerce_order_itemmeta.order_item_id = wp_woocommerce_order_items.order_item_id
WHERE wp_posts.post_type IN ('shop_order','shop_subscription') 
GROUP BY wp_users.ID
```

It returns too large of a SUM of $340k instead of $4k, shown in second image here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/baDwi.jpg

Can anyone spot the error I made? Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this one out

```
SELECT users.ID as userID,
       posts.post_date,
       posts.post_type,
       users.user_email,
       fname.meta_value as firstName,
       lname.meta_value as lastName,
       SUM(itemmeta.meta_value) as userTotal
FROM wp_posts posts
  INNER JOIN wp_postmeta postmeta
     ON postmeta.post_id = posts.ID
     AND postmeta.meta_key = '_customer_user'
  INNER JOIN wp_users users
     ON users.ID = postmeta.meta_value
  INNER JOIN wp_woocommerce_order_items items
     ON items.order_id = posts.ID
  INNER JOIN wp_woocommerce_order_itemmeta itemmeta
     ON itemmeta.order_item_id = items.order_item_id
     AND itemmeta.meta_key = '_line_total'
  LEFT JOIN wp_usermeta fname
     ON fname.user_id = users.ID 
     AND fname.meta_key = 'billing_first_name'
  LEFT JOIN wp_usermeta lname
     ON lname.user_id = users.ID 
     AND lname.meta_key = 'billing_last_name'
WHERE posts.post_type IN ('shop_order','shop_subscription') 
GROUP BY users.ID
```

I introduced aliases for the tables and replaced your case constructs with left joins.

It seems that you need to specify the meta_keys as conditions because otherwise you will join rows that will not match the meta_key. This in turn will multiply the joined rows from wp_woocommerce_order_itemmeta and therefore the attributes you want to sum up.

Comment: Thanks! You saved the day! It's still giving me a slightly different total than if I manually add up all the rows, but I should be able to figure out what else is wrong.

Comment: Did you adjusted you first query according to my suggedtion? And please accept my answer when it helped you.

Comment: Yep, I got it working now. I had a typo when I copied the query. Thanks again for all your help! Unfortunately I'm too new to upvote your answer, but I marked it as the answer.